# Mongodb not returning specific fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoskin, co-monk

I am trying to return only one field `sessions` from a document.

I'm using the current query (it returns the entire document):

```
yield users.findOne({
    '_id': id // var id holds object id ObjectId("560ae1dc53cb3222679430f1")
}, {
    '_id': 0, // <--- being ignored
    'sessions': 1 // <--- being ignored
});
```

I tried in mongo shell and this works as it should:

```
db.users.find({"_id":ObjectId("560ae1dc53cb3222679430f1")},{"sessions":1,"_id":0}).pretty() // <--- works
```

I'm currently using [co-monk](https://github.com/tj/co-monk) which is based off of [mongoskin](https://github.com/kissjs/node-mongoskin). So it should work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not made clear in the documentation, but there is an explicit key name syntax to the "options" object :

```
yield users.findOne({ '_id': id }, { 'fields': { '_id': 0, 'sessions': 1  }});
```

So it works a bit differently to the MongoDB shell API. The same applies for other options such as `sort`.

Comment: Wow it works. Can you link where you found this out, would love to read the rest of it (will be needing it).

Comment: Found out that I should of been looking at https://github.com/christkv/node-mongodb-native as mongoskin wraps it

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer didn't work in my case, so I went digging through the docs and this is what I found for the fields option: **Deprecated Use options.projection instead**, and got the respective warning in the console. Chaining in *.project()* as with *.find()* didn't work for *.findOne()* in my case, so it has to be in the options using projection:

```
yield users.findOne({
    '_id': id 
}, { projection: { //projection rather than fields
    '_id': 0,
    'sessions': 1 }
});
```

Here it is: [mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Collection.html#findOne)

Answer (score 0):

**2022 update**

You have to use projection in latest update.

Reference:
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/quick-reference/

Here is a sample code for this question.

```
const ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;

var query = { _id: ObjectId('your search object id here') };
var options = { projection: { sessions: 1, _id: 0 } };

users.findOne(query, options);
```